# Doubt about usage of a preposition

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am an english learner. I would like to ask you a very quick question about the usage of the preposition ***of*** or ***in*** in this sentence.

Which is better to write?

> He is one of the best students **in** my university course.

or

> He is one of the best students **of** my university course.

Why one preposition and not the other?

Comment: I'd choose 'on'.

Comment: Either one works. _Of_ suggests that he is closely identified with the class, whereas _in_ does not; it's strictly accounting -- his name is on the list.

Comment: thanks a lot! Before writing the post grammarly suggest me to put "in" instead "of", but @JohnLawler you help me to fix my doubt. Thanks